# How to avoid the use of backslash and "use" in namespaced classes for calling global classes?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a lot of namespaced classes in which i do a lot of calls to global classes.

I have 2 solutions:

1- I use the backslash "\" in each global class calling

```
namespace Admin;

class UserController extends \BaseController{
  [...]
  public function update($id){
    $user = new \User::find($id);
    $user->username = \Input::get('username');
    $user->password = \Hash::make(\Input::get('password'));
    return \Redirect::action('UserController@index');
  }
  [...]
}
```

2- I declare the usage of a lot of global classes at the beginning of each namespaced class with "use"

```
namespace Admin;
use \BaseController;
use \User;
use \Input;
use \Hash;
use \Redirect;

class UserController extends BaseController{
  [...]
  public function update($id){
    $user = new User::find($id);
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    return Redirect::action('UserController@index');
  }
  [...]
}
```

In both cases I think the code is not so elegant.
Is there a way to avoid this?
I would like to mantain the namespace and call global classes without "using" al of them in each namespaced class.

Comment: Those are basically the two options you have. Pick one.

Comment: I believe the 2nd method you mention is more appropriate as it defines clearer the namespaces you use. Also note that you can use "use User;" instead of "use \User;"

Comment: Yes but do I have to repeat the "use"s for every namespaced class? Can I define a list of "use"s for an entire namespace only one time?

Answer (score 6):

When you `use` you don't have to put slashes, you can just:

```
use BaseController;
use User;
use Input;
use Hash;
use Redirect;
```

It's implied that PHP will try to get those starting from root (\).

But you cannot avoid `use` if your classes are namespaced. That's the way to tell PHP that those files are not in the same namespace of yours.

Comment: As I commented above... do I have to repeat this set of "use"s for every namespaced class? I would like to define them only once for an entire namespace... Is there a way?